# How to dump an in-memory generated class to a file

Tags: java, reflection

I am getting some exceptions in a generated class `sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1548.invoke()`. Is it possible to dump its code to a file or browse it somehow at runtime? It's part of a very large application with many third-party libs and I do not even know which library generated this class in the first place.

--

The last stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@60b4bc67
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1548.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.github.mustachejava.reflect.ReflectionWrapper.call(ReflectionWrapper.java:63) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.mustachejava.reflect.ReflectionObjectHandler.unwrap(ReflectionObjectHandler.java:34) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.mustachejava.reflect.guards.WrappedGuard.apply(WrappedGuard.java:33) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.mustachejava.reflect.GuardedWrapper.guardCall(GuardedWrapper.java:40) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.mustachejava.reflect.ReflectionWrapper.call(ReflectionWrapper.java:57) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.mustachejava.reflect.GuardedBinding.get(GuardedBinding.java:66) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.mustachejava.codes.DefaultCode.get(DefaultCode.java:105) ~[compiler-0.8.13.jar:na]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

(There are no more "caused by" traces)

Comment: Then I don't see how you could save it, since you don't know where it's generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is generated by the JVM to optimise the use of reflection.  This should be the cause of an error unless there is a bug in the JVM, in which case you need to upgrade.  More likely there is a bug in the code this method calls.

Comment: Yes but is there an API to dump a loaded class? Also added the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: You can dump a class which is loaded by a ClassLoader. However, classes which are generated dynamically are not stored in a way which can be accessed.

Comment: Java 7 update 51 is not particularly old.  However, IMHO if you are getting an error inside the reflection code you are not going be able to debug it even if you could access the byte code.

Comment: Yes I thought so too but usually in that case I get an InvocationTargetException, but not in this case for some reason.

Comment: @rustyx I agree, there is something wrong with how the JVM is handling this. I would try a different version of Java.

Comment: This code seems to be generated by `sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator` and is a reflection optimization called "[inflation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/reflection_a_memory_viewpoint3?lang=en)". Indeed, the first 15 invocations of the same method throw a more descriptive exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`. So no need to decompile this code.